A new basis for chromatic polynomials
Given a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices, its chromatic polynomial $P(G,x)$ is a function that gives the number of proper colorings of G using $x$ colors.
When $P(G,x)$ is written using the basis $\{x, \ldots , x^n\}$, it is known that the coefficients of $x, \ldots , x^n$ alternate in signs; when $P(G,x)$ is written using the basis $\{ (x)_0, (x)_1, \ldots, (x)_n \}$, where $(x)_k = x(x-1)(x-2) \cdot \ldots \cdot (x-(k-1))$ denotes the falling factorial, then its coefficients are nonnegative.
I verified at SageMath that, up to $9$ vertices, when $P(G,x)$ is written using the basis $\{ x^{n-1}(x)_1, x^{n-2}(x)_2, \ldots, (x)_n \}$, then its coefficients are also nonnegative, but I could not find an example of graph with at least one negative coefficient and I have not found any proof of this fact in the literature.
Is anyone aware of this result? This question arises from work in progress by Petter Brändén and Leonardo Saud.

Careful that $x^n(x)_0=x^{n-1}(x)_1$.

Oh, yes! You are correct. Fixed now :)

Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't this follow from induction on the deletion-contraction recurrence? Reordering the formula gives $P(G-uv,k)=P(G,k)+P(G/uv,k)$, and if $G$ has $n$ vertices then $G/uv$ has $n-1$ vertices, thus has nonnegative coefficients by the induction assumption. So deleting edges cannot decrease the coefficients of the chromatic polynomial in that basis. Since any graph can be obtained by starting from a complete graph (with polynomial $(x)_n$) and deleting some edges, we are done.

@pregunton For an $n$ vertex graph, every polynomial in the basis has degree $n$. So the basis polynomials are different for an $n-1$ vertex graph,

@GordonRoyle Oh, sorry, you're right, I didn't read the question properly.

In case anyone stumbles across this question, the statement (that all the coefficients in this basis are non-negative) is not true.
The complete bipartite graph $K_{7,7}$ has the following coefficients in the given basis, where the third coefficient is negative.
                                            0]
[                                      1/4096]
[                            -11249/725594112]
[                      961739905/371504185344]
[         1043130571860013/241864704000000000]
[           395726588093431/20155392000000000]
[  23163981271533774127/553294399795200000000]
[168461889135965303089/1770542079344640000000]
[634055484774359381981/4097540240769024000000]
[    3111149918504247421/14634072288460800000]
[    3312627477466754807/15458690647572480000]
[          4914499543566463/30672005253120000]
[              13048613951497/172613016576000]
[                        116914351/6227020800]


I am aware that this is difficult for a third-party to check, but the counterexample has been confirmed by the originators of the question.
